# PHP - assigning values in a function argument - good practice?

Tags: php

Setting variable values inside a function call - I don't see this a lot, is this considered good practice?

```
function myUpdate($status){
    ...
}

myUpdate($status = 'live');
```

I personally like it because it's more descriptive. I see it more frequently the other way around, ie., assigning a default value in the function definition.

Comment: You do know that doing that will not affect the function's execution in any way, and only assign a local variable in the calling scope?

Comment: @Rijk Yes, it works because the result of an assignment in PHP is the value assigned.

Comment: @Rijk: It works, but read Jani's comment to see what exactly it does (hint: it does something *no sane person would **ever** want to do*).

Comment: I was just kidding -- see my answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a very bad idea, because it's basically code obfuscation. php does **not** support keyword arguments, and that can lead to weird stuff. Case in point:

```
function f($a, $b){
    echo 'a: ' . $a . "\n";
    echo 'b: ' . $b . "\n";
}
f($b='b-value', $a='a-value');
```

This program does not only output

```
a: b-value
b: a-value
```

but also *defines* the variables `$b` and `$a` in the global context. This is because

```
f($b='b-value', $a='a-value');
// is the same thing as ...
$b = 'b-value';
$a = 'a-value';
f($b, $a);
```

There are a few good practices one can do to make remembering method arguments easier:

- Configure your editor/**IDE** to show the signature of functions on highlight.
- If a function has lots of arguments that describe some kind of state, consider moving it into an **objec**t (that holds the state instead)
- If your function just needs lots of arguments, make it take an **array** for all non-essential ones. This also allows the method caller not to worry at all about the multitude of options, she just needs to know the ones she's interested in.

Comment: it's not code obfuscation. If you have 3 bool parameters in the function, adding variables with descriptive ways actually improves readability.

Comment: @Darhazer It does improve readability until someone changes the method's signature. From then on, this practice will *actively mislead* programmers about the actual method signature.

Answer (score 2):

All kidding aside, seriously why do you use it? You have to realize it's something totally different than assigning a default value. What you're doing here is assigning the value to a variable, and then passing that variable to the function. The result is, that after the function call, the `$status` varialbe is still defined.

```
myUpdate( $status = 'live' );
echo $status; // "live"
```

Even if this is what you want, I'd say it's *less* descriptive than just splitting it out in two lines.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not because it's extra code. Try:

`myUpdate('live' /*status*/, 42 /*maxTries*/);`

Or if you really wanted named parameters, you could use a map:

```
myUpdate(array(
    'status' => 'live'
));
```

Normally it would kill type safety, but PHP doesn't have any, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, default value is different thing.

```
// if you call myUpdate without argument, it will have $status with value live
function myUpdate($status = 'live'){

}
```

Calling this:

```
myUpdate($status = 'live');
```

is equivalent to:

```
myUpdate('live');
```

with the only difference being that after the call, if you call it like `myUpdate($status = 'live');` you will keep the `$status` var with value `live` in the scope where you called the function, not inside it.

But IMHO its much more readable to do it like this:

```
$status = 'live';
myUpdate($status);
```